# How to define text as h1 in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Type.kt Typography I defined h1 TextStyle like this:

```
h1 = TextStyle(
     fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
     fontWeight = FontWeight.W500,
     fontSize = 70.sp,
     color = Color(0xFFF8F9FC)
),
```

Now how can I define the Text widget to be an h1 so these TextStyles applies automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the current theme `h1` from any `@Composable` with `MaterialTheme.typography.h1`, so your widget might look like this:

```
@Composable
fun TextH1(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Text(
        text = text,
        modifier = modifier,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1,
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you plan on using your style globally for all text that you want identified as h1, you should create a custom composable for that and apply your style there:

```
@Composable
fun TextH1(
   text: String,
   modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
   Text(text = text, modifier = modifier, textStyle = h1)
}
```

Alternatively, you could use CompositionLocal, but that tends to become cumbersome if used extensively.